# New York not found in French weather app

Tags: ios, applications, internationalization

I have one iphone in English, one in French. 
In the weather app, in English, I can find "New York, NY" no issues.
In the French version, New York simply does not appear in the search results!
Known issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for "JFK" gives me "WNYC". It is the same weather in both cities.